# ¿Cómo lleno un multiselect con jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, multiselect

Estoy haciendo un `multiselect` que se llene automaticamente trayendo los datos de la base de datos con una petición en `ajax` lo que hago es que el `php` devuelvo ya la estructura `html` y con `jquery` se lo mando al `html`, pero cuando intento llenarlo, pues no funciona, sí alguien sabe y me puede ayudar, se lo agradezco.

`PHP`

```
if($empleados != null){
                $html = "<li id='0' data='0'>Seleccionar empleado</li>";            
                $cantidad = 0;
                if($registros != null){
                    if(count($empleados) > count($registros) ){
                        $cantidad = count($empleados); 
                    }else{
                        $cantidad = count($registros);
                    }

                    for ($i=0, $j= 0; $i < $cantidad; $i++) {   
                        if(isset($emp)){
                            if($empleados[$i]["id_empleado"] == $emp){
                                $html .= "<li id='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}' data='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']} selected>{$empleados[$i]['nombres']} {$empleados[$i]['apellidos']}</li>";
                                $j++;
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }                 
                        if($empleados[$i]["id_empleado"] == $registros[$j]['id_empleado']){
                            $j++;
                        }else{
                            $html .= "<li id='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}' data='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}>{$empleados[$i]['nombres']} {$empleados[$i]['apellidos']}</li>";
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    for ($i=0; $i < count($empleados); $i++) {                     
                        $html .= "<li id='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}' data='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}'>{$empleados[$i]['nombres']} {$empleados[$i]['apellidos']}</li>";                    
                    }

                }
                echo $html;
            }else{
                echo "<li id='0' data='0'>No hay empleados</li>";
            }
```

Fíjense más en las cadenas ya que todo lo que hago ahí es para que no haya ciertos problemas al llenarlo

`JQuery`

```
function llenarEmpleados(){
        var sede = $("#sede").val();
        var fecha = $("#fecha").val();
        var parametros = {
            'sede' : sede,
            'fecha' : fecha            
        };

        if(sede != 0 && fecha != ""){
            $.ajax({
                data: parametros,
                url: '/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=llenarEmpleados',
                type: 'post',
                success: function (response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $("multiselect ul").html(response);                    
                    $("#empleado").attr("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        }else{
            var html = "<option value'0'>Seleccionar empleado</option>"
            $("#empleado").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#empleado").html(html);
        }
    }
```

`HTML`

```
<select type="text" size="5" class="custom-select" id="empleado" name="empleado"  multiple>
                        <option value="0" disable selected>Seleccionar empleado</option>
                    </select>
```

`Multiselect jquery`

```
$(function () { 
        $('#empleado').multiselect({ 
            buttonText: function(options, select) {
                console.log(select[0].length);
                if (options.length === 0) {
                    return 'Sin Seleccion';
                }
                if (options.length === select[0].length) {
                    return 'Todos ('+select[0].length+')';
                }
                else if (options.length >= 4) {
                    return options.length + ' Seleccionados';
                }
                else {
                    var labels = [];
                    console.log(options);
                    options.each(function() {
                        labels.push($(this).val());
                    });
                    return labels.join(', ') + '';
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Uno de los valores que retorna, sería:

```
<li id='0' data='0'>Seleccionar empleado</li><li id='01' data='01'>Manuel  Chará</li><li id='26' data='26'>Gabriel Caballero Bedoya</li><li id='35' data='35'>Karen Lizeth Torres</li><li id='39' data='39'>Juan Manuel Astudillo</li><li id='40' data='40'>Karen Sofia Garcia</li><li id='42' data='42'>Dylan Restrepo Calvache</li><li id='45' data='45'>Anderson Ruiz</li><li id='48' data='48'>Juan Felipe Bonilla</li>
```

Comment: En el success del ajaxcall no deberías insertarle el response a $("#empleado").html(response); porque estas tratando de agregarselo al multiselect y no existe como tal

Comment: En ese caso es por sí no se hace la consulta, y no ha entrado por ahí en lo que he hecho

Comment: De hecho el success es lo que te retorna la consulta, por eso te comento que no se inserta por eso. quieres decir que se va al else y por eso no lo inserta?

Comment: Por eso, el entra por ahí, por eso por lo que ví que esa era la forma de llenar el multiselect solo lo cambié ahí, porque por el select no se va

Comment: el response que valor trae, lo podrías incluir?

Comment: @RicardoPérez listo

Comment: Pero si estas usando un <select> deberias usar <option>, porque el <li> es para los <ul>, es por eso que no se muestran

Comment: Pero pues por lo que he visto el multiselect funciona distinto, y pues el <option> no me funcionó y ahora tampoco así

Comment: Puedes probar este ejemplo y decirme si es lo que necesitas?

https://jsfiddle.net/RicardoP/Lhr3ozmj/

Comment: No sé que pasa pero no me funciona

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98342/discussion-between-ricardo-perez-and-daxtter77).

Comment: Ya lo solucioné xd

Comment: ¿Qué resulto ser al final?

Comment: Lo que estaba haciendo desde un principio con el option estaba bien, solo hacía falta hacer que el multiselect reconociera esos nuevos datos que llegaban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucioné el problema al momento de llenarlo en `jquery` le mandé a decir que después de insertarlo que volviera a reconstruir el multiselect y así carga los nuevos datos.
Se hace de esta manera

```
$.ajax({
                data: parametros,
                url: '/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=llenarEmpleados',
                type: 'post',
                success: function (response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#empleado").html(response);    
                    $("#empleado").multiselect("rebuild"); //Se agrega esto
                    $("#empleado").attr("disabled", false);
                }
            });
```

`PHP` devolviendo los `option`

```
if($empleados != null){
                $html = "<option value='0'>Seleccionar empleado</option>";            
                $cantidad = 0;
                if($registros != null){
                    if(count($empleados) > count($registros) ){
                        $cantidad = count($empleados); 
                    }else{
                        $cantidad = count($registros);
                    }

                    for ($i=0, $j= 0; $i < $cantidad; $i++) {   
                        if(isset($emp)){
                            if($empleados[$i]["id_empleado"] == $emp){
                                $html .= "<option value='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}' selected>{$empleados[$i]['nombres']} {$empleados[$i]['apellidos']}</option>";
                                $j++;
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }                 
                        if($empleados[$i]["id_empleado"] == $registros[$j]['id_empleado']){
                            $j++;
                        }else{
                            $html .= "<option value='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}'>{$empleados[$i]['nombres']} {$empleados[$i]['apellidos']}</option>";
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    for ($i=0; $i < count($empleados); $i++) {                     
                        $html .= "<option value='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}'>{$empleados[$i]['nombres']} {$empleados[$i]['apellidos']}</option>";                    
                    }

                }
                echo $html;
```

Gracias a [@Ricardo Pérez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/30865/ricardo-p%c3%a9rez) por su ayuda!